# Reports will no longer generate pdfs:Shows HTTP 500 error

Tags: wordpress, error, pdf, debugging

Recently we have been getting an error when attempting to generate pdfs. The only change of note has been that our server just upgraded to FreeBSD 10. When the process is run I get a HTTP 500 error. I have looked at the error logs and am unsure that it is showing the error. Listed below is the error that is repeated in the log. This is a Civi (4.7.29) install via wordpress (4.9.4). Any help is appreciated.

```
#1 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(833): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("We can't load the requested web page. This page requires cookies to be enable...")
#2 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(828): CRM_Core_Controller->invalidKeyCommon()
#3 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(312): CRM_Core_Controller->invalidKey()
#4 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(204): CRM_Core_Controller->key("CRM_Report_Form_Contact_Summary", TRUE, FALSE)
#5 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller/Simple.php(66): CRM_Core_Controller->__construct(NULL, TRUE, NULL, "CRM_Report_Form_Contact_Summary", FALSE, FALSE)
#6 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(84): CRM_Core_Controller_Simple->__construct("CRM_Report_Form_Contact_Summary", NULL, NULL, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
#7 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Report/Page/Instance.php(89): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Report_Form_Contact_Summary", NULL, NULL)
#8 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(309): CRM_Report_Page_Instance->run((Array:4), NULL)
#9 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#10 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#11 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1216): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#12 [internal function](): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#13 /wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:1))
#14 /wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#15 /wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#16 /wp-admin/admin.php(224): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#17 {main}

[message] => We can't load the requested web page. This page requires cookies to be enabled in your browser settings. Please check this setting and enable cookies (if they are not enabled). Then try again. If this error persists, contact the site administrator for assistance.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Site Administrators: This error may indicate that users are accessing this page using a domain or URL other than the configured Base URL. EXAMPLE: Base URL is http://example.org, but some users are accessing the page via http://www.example.org or a domain alias like http://myotherexample.org.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Error type: Could not find a valid session key.
[code] =>
```

Comment: Are you using wkhtmltopdf?  If so, does that need upgrading?

Comment: No we are using the default PDF utility. We have thought about using wkhtmltopdf though we would need to compile it for FreeBSD 10.

Comment: What did you use before FreeBSD 10. Also FreeBSD or Linux?

Comment: In your `civicrm.settings.php` file the variable CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL is set. Are you accessing the site on the same url?

Comment: Yes, all the resource urls seemed to be correct in review.

Answer (score 1):

After updating to the latest CiviCRM it seems the problem was corrected.